# How to shift except in the first element in array Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Initial code:
 `var ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

I want to `shift` starting from second element and add last element. I try to using `shift()` and `splice()` but doesn't work and maybe something wrong on my code. 
any idea to fix it?

thank you

```js
var ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

ar.splice(5,1,"0").shift();

console.log(ar)
```

expected result `[1,3,4,5,6,0]`

Comment: `ar.aplice(5,1,"0")` returns an array of the removed items ... i.e. `[6]` ... that's the array you're shifting

Comment: what you expected result implies is you need to `ar.splice(1,1); ar.push('0');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a little slice and concat?

```js
var ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var result = ar.slice(0, 1).concat(ar.slice(2)).concat(0)

console.log(result)
```

Or maybe some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const [first, , ...next] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

console.log([first, ...next, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try ES6 rest operator

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5]  
const [firstItem, ...otherArray] = array
const newArray = [ ...otherArray, 0]


   
// or direct array assign 
// const [firstItem, ...otherArray] = [1,2,3,4,5]
   
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: sorry, forget add new value (const newArray = [ ...otherArray, 0]), now return correct result. Thx!

Comment: 2 is being discarded so add an extra comma  [firstItem,, ...otherArray] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

ar.splice(1,1)
ar.push(0)

console.log(ar)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function shift(arr, start, newElement) {
  const arr1 = []
  const rest = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < start; i++) {
    arr1.push(arr[i]);
  }
  for (let i = start + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    rest.push(arr[i]);
  }
  rest.push(newElement)
  return [...arr1, ...rest]
}
console.log(shift(array, 1, "0"))
console.log(shift(array, 2, "0"))
```